# Nginx webdav fcgiwrap %20/space folders

Tags: nginx, webdav

I have nginx server with fcgiwrap and webdav and simple cgi file explorer.
I try to go to folder url throught web browser with spaces but its creating new folder with %20 in name.

Example:
Folder:

```
$url/path/to/direc tory/
```

when i go to that url its not going to "direc tory" folder but creating new
`direc%20tory` folder.
I can open files with spaces but not folders.

Its a nginx problem or fcgiwrap?

In nginx log i have `GET $url/path/to/direc%20tory/`

Comment: Urls cannot contain spaces. Instead of a space, they will be encoded as %20. This is normal.

Comment: Yes i know but why when i access file i can watch movie but can i acces folder with spaces in url its not showing me a folder contaent with spaces but its create another folder with %20 in name its strange

Comment: I think problem will be with nginx because nginx translate space to %20 and pass that to fcgi and fcgi execute it a create new folder with that name, how change to pass to fcgi correct url?